# Updating Customer Credit Card with PHP & Stripe

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add this script to my Wordpress website that I found on Stripes documentation but I am a little confused as to how to enhance it more to know when the user already has a card on file it needs to update it rather than creating that customer again.

The code I was originally using can be seen here:
https://gist.github.com/bateller/154c6e5d1f6e0e53e527

This is that code with my edits to try and make it update: 
http://pastebin.com/B3LXZpWq

I can't find any information anywhere that seems to make sense to me. Hopefully someone can break it down and help me understand before I loose my mind.

Comment: You should include the code you need help with directly in the question itself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please follow the tutorial before asking question. You must need to show your specific problem with related code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Managed Accounts

[Stripe - Managed Accounts - https://stripe.com/docs/connect/managed-accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/managed-accounts)

You get a greater freedom when it comes to things like updating details and it is also a little stricter but worth it for the added API features.